# text view return null

Tags: android, textview, navigation-drawer

I'm working with android studio 2.2 and I used navigation drawer activity. then I'd like to change the text in the nav_header_layout from code, but when i used findViewById in the code to index the TextView which is in the nav_header_layout,  it returns null. Is there any way to fix it?

here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.nexmo.sdk.sample.verifysample.Dashboard"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Android"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nav_number"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

java code

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TextView textv=(TextView)findViewById (R.id.nav_number);
    textv.setText("new string");
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

Comment: Is the xml above `activity_dashboard.xml`?

Comment: I cant see any problem your code... check whether your referring correct layout or not setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard

Comment: Where is ViewPager, tablayout ???

Comment: actually i combined navigation drawer and tabbed layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want access the nav_header_layout, you can access.

```
  NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        if (headerView != null) {
           TextView myTextView = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_YOUR_TEXTVIEW);
            if(myTextView!=null){
               myTextView.setText("Hello");
            }
        }
```